# C# windows application not closing

Tags: c#

I have a C# windows application. I placed it on a test server, whose set up is not controlled by my company and neither is the seurity context. I double click the exe. App runs and i see my form. I close the application, i open task manager and i still see a foot print of the applicatiion.

taskkill does not seem to remove it and it is still running in task manager.

how do i check if any resource is still being held?

Answer (score 5):

The likely cause is that a background thread is still running after your application is closed.  Depending on your framework and application configuration a background thread can cause a process to keep running even after the main window is closed.

Do you have any threads in your process?  If so make sure to close them out when the main application window is closing.  A good place to do this is in the OnClosing method of a Windows Form

Answer (score 4):

Abusing Application.DoEvents() is another way to get into this kind of trouble.  If you cannot kill the .exe from TaskMgr, your app is stuck waiting for a driver to finish an I/O request.

Comment: nobugz: i have not abuse application.doevents. trying to use fusionlogs to see whats going on