# C# windows application not closing

Tags: c#

my post is same like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465306/c-windows-application-not-closing)... but that post didn't solve'd my question, so my question is.

m building a win app in c#, and in that im using `backgroundworkder thread` and `Application.DoEvents`. here's my code:

```
for(int i=0;i<gridview.rows.count-1;i++)
{
  if (backThread.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
        string TargetFrame = "";
        byte[] vPost = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("_PostData");
        string Header = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" + "\n" + "\r";
        autoWebPage.Navigate("https://xyz.com", TargetFrame, vPost, Header);
        while (car == false)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
}
```

and this loop is under `BackGroundWorker_DoWork()` event, The Problem is m not able to close the form or application, i.e in taskmanager my app is still running, i dn't know what is the cause, maybe `Application.DoEvents` or `BackGroundWorker thread`, i google'd about this issue, but i didn't get any clear idea.. i tried to close the form using this:

```
//Application.Exit();
//mainmdiForm.Dispose();
//mainmdiForm.Close();
//backGroundWorker.CancelAsync();
```

but no success. And one more thing while searchin' about this issue on google,, i got many results sayin' `Application.DoEvents()` is an EVIL, m curious why is that so ?

Comment: Are there any reason at all for you to call Application.DoEvents() here? I have a feeling that you don't understand how threading and message loops are working

Comment: yes thr's a purpose for Application.DoEvents(); coz, `autoweb.navigate` fires the autoweb.DocumentCompletedEvent(), since `autoweb.navigate` is in for-loop, that documentComplete is not getting fired, that's y i used Application.DoEvent();

Comment: Hm, it just doesn't feel right that you call the navigate-method from a different thread. (It's a web browser object, right?)

Comment: yes its a webbrowser control object..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is general advice how to solve these issues.

1. Start your application in debug
2. Close it
3. Go to [Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15yf86f.aspx) window
4. Enter threads one by one until yo find the one that blocks app from closing

Comment: @FosterZ ok, then it will not exit debug mode and you will be able to perform steps 3 and 4

Comment: thanx i'll debug it, and why people calling `Application.DoEvent` as an EVIL.. m not suppose to use that ?

Comment: @FosterZ what about just googling "Application.DoEvent evil" ?

Answer (score 1):

while trying to close the app set the `BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync()` method.
And in you loop check the value of the `BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending` Property

Comment: m sry tht i didn't poste'd that part here but i already done that what you were sayin' no sucess..

Comment: You still have the `while (car == false)` that can block it.

Comment: m taking care of that 'while(car==false)'

Comment: what is car? when do you assign true to it?

Comment: its C.A.R (CompleteAutoRecharge)..n this just a bool flag, this is set to true when navigate method of WebBrowser Control fires `WebPage_DocumentCompleted(){car=true}`