# C# in Windows Application Closing or Exit

Tags: c#, winforms, exit

When I click the X (windows close button on corner top right) is `application.exit` or `this.close` run implicitly?

Because every time that I change my programme and compile it, it cannot be compiled because it is in use by another process, So I have to kill it every time on windows task manager.

Because of that, I think that my application not really close / exit properly.

```
namespace FrontEnd_Offline
{
    public partial class Main_Usr : Form
    {
        public Main_Usr()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.IsMdiContainer = true;
        }

        private void barButtonItem_CreateOrdre_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void barButtonItem_OrdreListe_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Ordre_Liste f = new Ordre_Liste();
            f.MdiParent = this;

            f.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you run any background threads in your application? 
Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465306/c-sharp-windows-application-not-closing

Comment: Thanks you the different from stackoverflow.com/questions/465306/ is i can kill my programm on task manager.

Answer (score 3):

It is conditional but that's not the problem.  All your forms got disposed but your code didn't stop running.  The common reasons for this:

- starting a thread without setting its IsBackground property to true and not ensuring the thread is terminated when your main form closes.
- using Application.DoEvents() in your code.

You can use Debug + Break All, then Debug + Windows + Threads to see what code is still running.  Some of the threads shown there are not your threads so avoid chasing the ones that don't show a good stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You try calling the `base.dispose(true)` method to fully exit the application. You can write this code into the event of close button. Even though it might not be considered the best of programming practices.